# Popping up custom module in Dotnetnuke 6 using UrlUtils class's PopUpUrl method

Tags: c#, .net, dotnetnuke, modalpopup

I am new to DNN and working with custom module in DNN, I have created one Module and then a tab in DNN and placed that custom module on the page. So far so good but now I want to popup that module in a modal popup similar to the login module, using DotNetNuke's `UrlUtils` class's `PopUpUrl` method, but it doesn't work and whole page is shown as normal page rather than a modal popup. The method I used is as follows:

1). I Created A Hyperlink and put it on my skin
2). on skin load i have written as follow

```
myLink.NavigateUrl = "http://www.abcd.com";
myLink.Attributes.Add("onclick","return" + UrlUtils.PopUpUrl(myLink.NavigateUrl, this, PortalSettings, true, false));
```

now on click of this hyperlink  the page from "http://www.abcd.com" should be open in popup
but it does not work....am i missing something...OR there is another way of doing this...??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue may be that there's no space between `return` and the pop-up URL in the `onclick` attribute.